# Fun Animated CSS3 404 Page?

Tags: javascript, css, http-status-code-404

I came across the following 404 page in my travels yesterday:
http://idzr.org/404

Is there a similar open-source script to achieve something similar? Obviously I cannot just pinch the JS/CSS from that site (even though I wish I could)

Comment: I wouldn't consider that one fun on my computer. It's really laggy!

Comment: that's awesome! I've never seen anything like that before.

Comment: GitHub has a great 404-page: https://github.com/404. Move your mouse over it :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you sorta can... In the source it lists their source, it says

> ...This animation is modified from one of the example from webkit.org's blog - http://webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/ You can read more about it if you are interested.

So check out that link.

Comment: The info is no longer correct: current WebKit browsers such as Chrome/Chromium and probably Safari on Windows support that as well. I can see it on Chromium/Linux for example.

Comment: The first sentence no, but the part saying "This animation is modified from..." was the more important part. I'm running chrome and I can see it as well.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I was referring only to the first part.

Comment: I deleted that part to avoid further confusion.